# Identifying international crossings in OSM

Tags: point, road, quickosm

I would like to identify international crossings between Italy and Austria in OSM, regardless the type of road.

Is there a way to identify such points using QuickOSM or should I do it manually, using a base map?

I extracted the road network pertaining to the Italian border region, but I cannot think of a flow of operations to identify such points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ways data for the border between Italy and Austria.

I used Overpass Turbo to create this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="2"]({{bbox}});
  
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I used only ways because we only need parts of the full national boundaries. Especially since the Italian borders are very long to the south and we don't need all that data.

I drew a BBOX that just contains the relevant border in Overpass Turbo. After drawing the bbox and running the query the result is this:

[image: BBOX with returned data]

You would then need to download the data (it's under "Export" in the menu), load into QGIS, possibly dissolve into one way (in QGIS).

The next steps depend on where you store the road network. If in some kind of database then also import the boundary way and run something like

```
select ST_intersection(roads.geom,border.geom) from osm_roads, border where STIntersects(roads.geom,border.geom)=True
```

If in shapefiles then you can run line intersection from the vector overlays. See https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=intersection#line-intersections .

Edit:

I used the above method to get a border GeoJSON, cleaned that up a little (removing the border with Slovenia), used dissolve to get a single line. Then I used the QuickOSM plugin to get all ways tagged `highway` in the vicinity of the Brenner pass. Then I ran the QGIS tool `line intersections` and used both layers as input. This is the result:

[image: line intersections border and highway around brenner pass]

Detailed analysis:

[image: hiking trail crosses border a lot]

The hiking trail follows the border and crosses it numerous times. Probably you need to constrain your query to ways tagged `highway=track` and above or you get lots of these kind of crossings.